# Creating multiple category drop down

Tags: functions, jquery, javascript, html, cms

I'm trying to figure out on how to create a multiple category drop down to filter different types of post

Here is an image of my work in progress

http://i255.photobucket.com/albums/hh140/testament1234/multiple_category_zpsa93a6f33.png

The category highlighted in a red box shape doesn't seem to be working. I'm not sure if it is because it has a conflict. I checked for any errors using firebug but nothing is displayed. I do not like to rely on plugins at the moment

**Here is my HTML code**

```
<h2>projects</h2>

<div class="filter_container">
        <?php wp_dropdown_categories( $args ); ?> 
</div>

<div class="filter_container">
        <?php wp_dropdown_categories( $args ); ?> 
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#cat{
background-image: url("images/form_arrow.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 80% center;
border: 0px none;
float: right;
font-family:'Sintony', sans-serif;
margin-right: -25px;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 5px;
width: 200px;

}

.filter_container{
border: 2px solid #8e8fbb;
float: right;
height: 30px;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
}
```

**JS:**

```
<!--DROPDOWN SORT CATEGORY -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var dropdown = document.getElementById("cat");
function onCatChange() {
    if ( dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value > 0 ) {
        location.href = "<?php echo get_option('home');
?>/?cat="+dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
    }
}
dropdown.onchange = onCatChange;
</script>
```

**Functions.php(Specify what categories to display)**

```
$args = array(
'show_option_all'    => '',
'show_option_none'   => '',
'orderby'            => 'ID', 
'order'              => 'ASC',
'show_count'         => 0,
'hide_empty'         => 1, 
'child_of'           => 0,
'exclude'            => '1,2,3',
'echo'               => 1,
'selected'           => 0,
'hierarchical'       => 0, 
'name'               => 'cat',
'id'                 => '',
'class'              => 'postform',
'depth'              => 0,
'tab_index'          => 0,
'taxonomy'           => 'category',
'hide_if_empty'      => false,
'walker'             => ''
);
```

-----UPDATED JS-----

```
<!--DROPDOWN SORT CATEGORY -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var dropdown = document.getElementById("cat1");
function onCatChange() {
    if ( dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value > 0 ) {
        location.href = "<?php echo get_option('home');
?>/?cat="+dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
    }
}
dropdown.onchange = onCatChange;
</script>


<!--DROPDOWN SORT CATEGORY -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var dropdown = document.getElementById("cat2");
function onCatChange() {
    if ( dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value > 0 ) {
        location.href = "<?php echo get_option('home');
?>/?cat="+dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
    }
}
dropdown.onchange = onCatChange;
</script
```

Comment: IDs must be unique, do you have two dropdowns that both have the ID 'cat'? This otherwise doesn't seem like a WordPress question.

Comment: It looks like the ID cat is placed in this code  <?php wp_dropdown_categories( $args ); ?> when i tried to inspect the element. Not sure how i can alter the ID

Answer (score 1):

Change `'id' => ''` in your `$args` to be unique values for each dropdown. If it's empty it defaults to the value of `name`, which is `cat` in both instances.

Comment: I tried your solution but same outcome i even changed the ID'S in the javascript to match the specified ID's in function.php or maybe i might be missing something. I also copied the 'args' in the function.php to change the ID's for the other dropdown_category. Please see updated code

Comment: It looks my code at functions.php is at fault basically i can't just copy '$args = array' and change the ID. I think i need set an ID or something

Comment: NVM i managed to fix the problem on my own lol. I just added '$args_cat1' & '$args_cat2' in the template and functions.php I wasn't really sure since i'm not fluent in Php so i just tried it out hoping it might work.